# Ionic 3 show data from api with token

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on project i need help . I need to show the data from api. client give me url and token . i need to know how i can show data from that api to my console ? (In website data is showing in console in json format but i need to show it in my app )

I try with one tutorial but it only show to get data from simple api not with token .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HospitalPage } from '../hospital/hospital';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';


@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

data: Observable<any>;


 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public httpClient: HttpClient, 
 public callNumber: CallNumber) {


  this.data = this.httpClient.get('http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_takaful/insurance-api/get_panel_hospitals.php?offset=0&limit=100');
this.data
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('my data: ', data);
})


  }
```

[image]
 it show error of access token which is obvious i dont add the token any one know how i can show it please  ?

Comment: What kind of token is it and how are you expected to send it.  first try to get it working in `postman`, so you already know what works and is expected?

Answer (score 1):

Your request should look like this (based of @Sergey Rudenko's answer). As it's a bearer token you should include this

```
getDataUsingToken1(token) {
    const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "token "+ token)};
    return this.http.get('http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_takaful/insurance-api/get_panel_hospitals.php?offset=0&limit=100', httpOptions)
};
```

Comment: sorry not sure this its bearer token or not i have token :ee66cf61762eab785b006186dbc8c980 i check it on postman i insert api and in authorization set key to token and value is token . and it is showing the data .

Comment: so you need to change the `Bearer` part into `token`, as far as i can tell from the screenshot.  I revised the code

Comment: Thanks for your help please update the code Thanks again

Comment: its showing error in this.http.get . Eorr is : Can no read property get is not defined

Comment: something else is going on then.  this is the basic form of making this call.  I'm using it over here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191215/discussion-between-jcuypers-and-umaiz-khan).

Answer (score 0):

So depending on which token it is sometimes you need to pass it as header and sometimes as url param. Try reaching out to your client and ask what type of token you have and how you are supposed to use it.

Here is approximately how it should eventually be (updated based on your comments):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  data: Observable<any>;
  token: string;


  constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController, 
      public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.token = "ee66cf61762eab785b006186dbc8c980";
  }

  getDataUsingToken() {
      const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders().set("token", this.token)};
      return this.httpClient.get('http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_takaful/insurance-api/get_panel_hospitals.php?offset=0&limit=100', httpOptions)
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getDataUsingToken().subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: its bearer token . when i add token in this code its showing error .

Comment: can you share more details how the token was advised to be used in your case?

Comment: sorry not sure  this its bearer token or not i have token :ee66cf61762eab785b006186dbc8c980 i check it on postman i insert api and in authorization set key to token and value is token . and it is showing the data .

Comment: and also it give error in this.http.get . eorr is get function is not define

Comment: Hey man, I updated my code a bit, can you try it out? @UmaizKhan. Just make sure you double check if token is correct etc

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have gotten to the bottom of this, unfortunately without a (quick) solution.

Postman launches very specific requests with arbitrary header fields **without** triggering 'pre-flight' behavior as happens in our requests.

[image]

The official specs says that any non-trivial requests (so-called pre-flight behavior) should trigger an initial **OPTIONS** call with the `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, listing the non-standard header you want to use.

[image]

When making requests through HttpClient / Axios / ... they all behave according to this official specification.  I haven't found a way to bypass/override this behavior.

Unfortunately, the remote server, only accepts this non-standard behavior and doesn't respond to any OPTIONS call you send to it.

Maybe there exists such a library, or postman just uses a custom built solution.  Hope this at least has helped a bit.